# linkedlist which links to itself?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

Is there a name for a linked list type structure where the head and tail nodes link to each other? In such a list you can obviously iterate through it forever as it double backs on itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called a [circular list](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/circularlist.html).

([Anders Hejlsberg's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) [favorite data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344737/what-is-your-favourite-data-structure-and-why/1344741#1344741) is a circular linked list)

Comment: That nist.gov page is very useful. I have not seen it before.

Comment: I found http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/ "Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures" ~2 years ago -- good site.

Answer (score 5):

Generally known as a [circular linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly-linked_vs._linearly-linked)